# Converting Dictionary<string, string> to object

Tags: c#, asp.net, converters

I have `Dictionary<string, string>` is projection of class.
For example:

```
public class AppSettings {
    public int? S { get; }
    public double? SS { get; }
    public string? SSS { get; }
    public bool? SSSS { get; }

    public G? G { get; }
}
public class G {
    public int[] GG { get; }
```

The dictionary values may be:

```
"S", "5"
"SS", "5.2"
"SSS", "string",
"SSSS", "true"
"G:GG", "[1, 2, 3]"
```

I want to deserialize this dictionary to the single object `AppSettings`.

I know there is built-in this type of deserializator in ASP.Net 6.0, but I can't find it in `ComponentModel.TypeConverter` which it refers to.

```
app.Configuration.Bind(new object());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below method :

```
static T ConvertDictionaryToObject<T>(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary) where T : new()
        {
            T obj = new T();
    
            foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
            {
                PropertyInfo property = typeof(T).GetProperty(kvp.Key);
    
                if (property != null)
                {
                    
                    object value = Convert.ChangeType(kvp.Value, property.PropertyType);
    
                    
                    property.SetValue(obj, value);
                }
            }
    
            return obj;
        }
```

Use it like :

```
var appSetting = ConvertDictionaryToObject<AppSettings>(dictionary);
```